# How Android Espresso click an item in Recycler View inside Recycler View?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have two layers of Recycler views, Main Recycler view contains dynamic Recycler views as items.

So, I need to click and assertion text inside items of inner Recycler views in Android Espresso, or any ideas.

[image]

Comment: Try to use the Espresso Test Recorder tool ( https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder ) in the Android Studio IDE. This will generate an Espresso test code for your test actions. Then open and edit this test actions to see where and how the inner Recyclerview is accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's must easier if I test inner recycler views separately